# Angular: how to hide and show product depending on filter settings

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I hide products when all `data-*` attributes does not matched filter, and show when at list one `data-*` attribute of a product matches one of filter.

**Categories** - 3 different categories(option, categories, and colors)

```
options = ['All','OptionA', 'OptionB', 'OptionC', 'OptionD'];
categories= ['All','CategoryA', 'CategoryB', 'CategoryC', 'CategoryD'];
colors = ['All','Green', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Pink'];

<div class="container optionContainer">
  <div class="option" 
     *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index" 
     (click)="toggleOption(i)"  
     [ngClass]="{'selected': optionDiv === i }"> 
    <span></span>
    <a>{{ option }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Product** - (In project i will pull all products from DB, and displayed with *ngFor). Products sent in JSON format.

```
<div class="box" data-option="OptionA" data-category="CategoryC" data-color="Pink">
      OptionA CategoryC <br/> Pink
</div>
```

Example: [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/7vUGMOt2L5Qmqbl3We4r/)

Comment: Why don't create an `array` of *products* then make a pipe? (In plunker it's hardcoded in template[**HTML**]).

Comment: I am not sure how to do it with pipe, I start working with angular like 3 days ago.

Comment: Please, include in your question what kind of response (the items) you're getting from your server and I can help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <input type = "text" [ngFormControl]="filterValue"/>
> //...
> //... component
> filterValue = new Control();
> ngOnInit(){
>   this.filterValue.valueChanges
>       .subscribe(filterValue => this.xxxService.getDataFromDb(filterValue)
>                     .subscribe(data => this.options = data) );
>
> }
> //...
> ```
>
> find data by filterValue in ther xxxService

i'm sorry .it seemed that i had not unstand your question.my english is poor.
i thought you would like to filter data from db.

if you want to write a pipe,you can do like this.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'productFilter'})
export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(options: any, option?: any /* your selected option */) {
    //... if option mached return at list one data-* else return null 
  }
}
```

import to your component and use it like "...options | productFilter: option "

i write an simple example

pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'textFilter'})
export class TextFilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(value: Array<string>, text?: string) {
    const _value: Array<string> = [];
    if (text) {
      for (const str of value){
        if (str.includes(text)) {
          _value.push(str);
        }
     }
      return _value;
    }
    return value;
 }

}
```

component

```
//... templete
  <p>{{fruits | textFilter: "p"}}</p>
//...
fruits: Array<string> = [];
ngOnInit() {
    this.fruits = [ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana' ];
}
```

result : apple